# Imagepicker for AVCaptureSession

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, avcapturesession

I implemented code for taking picture using `AVCaptureSession`. And i have button to pick image from Gallery. So, i need to use `UIImagePickerController` for picking image from gallery.

Is it possible to use `UIImagepicker` for picking Gallery and `AVCaptureSession` for taking picture. If i use this inside same app, appstore reject app or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure.  You want to create your UIImagePickerController with a sourceType of UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary:

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
picker.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I can't imagine that Apple would reject you for doing this in the same app that you're using AVCaptureSession - they're providing these classes to do exactly what you're proposing, after all.